# WSO2 Deploy existing application as SAAS

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant, saas

I gone through many of your documents. I understand that multi tenancy is built into the framework.

Lets say I have J2EE application already up and running. I would like to deploy it as multi-tenant SAAS application on WSO2. I would like to know what are the steps involved and what changes I should be making at the application level in order to make it a multi-tenant application?

Thanks,
Girish

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article on deploying an application as a SAAS app.

http://blog.cobia.net/cobiacomm/2013/09/10/creating-a-saas-app-with-the-multi-tenant-carbon-framework-step-1/